# Sumar dos datos de un modelo y que el resultado se guarde en la base de datos con django

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
idfactura = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
idempleado = models.ForeignKey(empleados, null=True, blank=True)
idproducto1 = models.ForeignKey(producto, null=True, blank=True)
idproducto2 = models.ForeignKey(producto, null=True, blank=True)
Fecha_factura = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
total = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

El valor de producto 1 y producto 2 ya están guardados, lo que necesito es que se guarde la suma en el valor de total, y no he encontrado como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer esto se debe sobrescribir la función `save` de esta forma:

```
class MiModelo(models.Model):
    idfactura = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idempleado = models.ForeignKey(empleados, null=True, blank=True)
    idproducto1 = models.ForeignKey(producto, null=True, blank=True)
    idproducto2 = models.ForeignKey(producto, null=True, blank=True)
    Fecha_factura = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        # Suponiendo que "valor" es el valor del producto
        self.total = self.idproducto1.valor + self.idproducto1.valor
        # para python 2.x la función super se escribe super(MiModelo, self)
        super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma correcta de hacerlo es sobrescribiendo el método `save` del formulario, quedando de siguiente forma:

```
class MiFormulario(forms.Modelform):
    # ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instancia = super().save(commit=False)
        # total = aqui debes obtener la suma de acuerdo a tu modelo y consideraciones
        instancia.total = total
        if commit:
            instancia.save()
        return instancia
```

Comment: he devuelto la respuesta a su forma original debido a que el calculo del total debe realizarse en la clase correspondiente al formulario como lo indico al inicio de la respuesta, y no en el Modelo como lo propone Saul Hormazabal